# JQGrid not reloading data after performing action on click of custom button

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

This is the code for my JQGrid

```
$("#vendor_match_grid").jqGrid({
    url: $("#hdnWebSericeAPIURL").val() + "/api/PRAClubbedVendor/ViewClubbedVendorMasterData/",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    height: 500,
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Vendor Number', index: 'Vendor_Number', editable: false },
        { name: 'Vendor Name', index: 'Vendor_Name', editable: true },
        { name: 'Clubbed Vendor Name', index: 'Clubbed_Vendor_Name', editable: true },
        { name: 'Phone Number', index: 'Phone_Number', editable: true },
        { name: 'Fax Number', index: 'Fax_Number', editable: true },
        { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', editable: true },
        { name: 'Street', index: 'Street', editable: true },
        { name: 'City', index: 'City', editable: true },
        { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', editable: true },
        { name: 'Region', index: 'Region', editable: true },
        { name: 'Is Active', index: 'IsActive', editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: { 'True': 'Active', 'False': 'InActive' } } },
        { name: 'TableFlag', index: 'TableFlag', editable: false, hidden: true }],
    pager: '#vendor_match_pagernav',
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20, 50, 100],
    viewrecords: true,
    sortable: true,
    sortname: "TableFlag",
    sortorder: "desc",
    search: true,
    searchOperators: true,
    stringResult: true,
    closeAfterSearch: true,
    caption: 'Clubbed Vendor Match',
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    autowidth: true,
    loadComplete: function () {        },
    onSelectRow: function (rowID) {        }
}).navGrid('#vendor_match_pagernav', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true }, {}, {}, {}, { closeAfterSearch: true });
```

Now, I am adding a custom button to it using this code

```
$("#vendor_match_grid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#vendor_match_pagernav', {
    caption: "Add vendor",
    id: "btnAddVendor",
        onClickButton: function () {}
        });
```

In the onClickFunction, I open a popup, add some data and make an ajax call and in the success of AJAX, I need to reload the grid. But the data is not reloading. The jqGrid becomes empty. I am not using loadonce, my data is not local. What could I be possibly doing wrong?

******UPDATE****** 
This is my AJAX call

```
 $.ajax({
        url: $('#hdnWebSericeAPIURL').val() + '/api/PRAClubbedVendor/FinalizeClubbedVendorMasterData/',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(clubbedVendorDataObject),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#vendor_match_grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" })
    .trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true, page: 1 }]);
            //$("#vendor_match_grid").trigger('reloadGrid');
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you please add the reload statement and AJAX call  here

Comment: @Runcorn I have updated the code in the post. I tried multiple ways to trigger the reload, two of these are mentioned in the above code.

Comment: So, Did you checked the response from jqGrid relaod. Open up the console and view the reload request to make sure that the correct JSON format is being returned from the response.

Comment: @Runcorn I already checked that. The data is in correct format and it is also coming to the loadComplete event but still I see the jqGrid empty :(

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger reload method call upon clicking on custom button which is added into Grid.

Comment: I am already doing that. The webservice is returning the data but it is not getting bound to the jqGrid